# What is the correct ingredient labeling order for cosmetics to comply with the FDA?

Tags: fda, labelling

On [21 CFR 701.3](https://www.fda.gov/cosmetics/cosmetics-labeling-regulations/summary-cosmetics-labeling-requirements#Declaration), *FDA Summary of Cosmetics Labeling Requirements, Declaration of Ingredients*, it states that "ingredients must be declared in descending order of predominance."

What is the definition of predominance as it is used here?

In food labeling, it is my understanding that ingredients for products sold in the United States are to be sorted by weight (descending). However, I am not sure the same applies to cosmetics. I have found a cosmetics product where the ingredients list differs from order-by-weight within the first few ingredients (much more than 1%).

Comment: order-by-weight isn't always practicable. Think about a drink: you don't mix them by weight but by volume. But density makes that a pain in the back: a drink that has equal volumes of vodka and Creme de Cassis in it would be 43.8% Vodka and 56.2% Creme de Cassis by weight, and have a volume that is somewhat less than twice its constituent's individual volumes (because all the ingredients can intermingle)